# Ordenar alfanuméricamente en SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Tengo una tabla en `sqlite` con valores con este:

**Nombre**
LN  9 2020     -- tiene un espacio en blanco entre LN y 9
LN10 2020
LN1  2020

Quisiera hacer una consulta y que se ordenaran los registros para obtener

LN1 2020
LN  9 2020
LN10 2020

> SELECT name FROM mitabla ORDER BY name

me saca el siguiente resultado:

LN  9 2020
LN1 2020
LN10 2020

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Cuantos LN tendrías,  LN23,  LN28, LNX?

Comment: muchos, más de  600

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza **Natural Sort Order** para ordenar cadenas alfanuméricas

```
SELECT name FROM mitabla ORDER BY name COLLATE naturalsort ASC
```

Comment: me da este error : could not prepare statement (1 no such collation sequence: naturalsort)

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQLite usas?

Comment: es la versión SQLite 3.32.3  https://github.com/storesafe/cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: quizas tenga que crear la tabla de alguna forma para que reconozca collation ?

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes tu consulta?

Comment: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mitabla(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,id_doc INTEGER, type VARCHAR(45), name VARCHAR (100), version BIGINT ); "

Comment: Creo que es mas por la versión de SQLite o la compatibilidad porque ya cree tu tabla con el código que enviaste, agregue los datos e hice la consulta que te pase y si lo hace correctamente